# How to select elements of document inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to make page which works like browser inspector. Basically I would like to be able to click on element of page and get an Xpath for that element. I created simple page that uses jQuery to load another page into div, but i'm stuck on getting to that inner page elements.

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $("#page").html('<object data="http://mypage.com" />');
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="page"></div>
</body>
```

using `$("#page").find("object")` selector I can reach to `object`, but i haven't found way to reach deeper to elements of document inside that `object`. Is there any way to select elements of that inner page or maybe there is a better way to do what I want to?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access inner `<objects>`'s document using the `contentDocument` property of the element. I.e.:

If you have something like:

```
<object data="blob:http://my-domain.com/resource-id: hidden;">
  #document
    <html>        
      <body>
        <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="blob:http://my-domain.com/resource-id" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="110">
       </body>
    </html>
  </object>
```

You could access the `embed` element doing so:

`$('object').contentDocument.body.children[0]`

Answer (score 1):

"The `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree."

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

I.e., use find to get all the elements matching the search criteria and children to get only immediate children.

Comment: I know how children() and find() work but I want to get to element inside object. With selector I've mentioned before I can reach to object, but if i use find() on object than I got nothing. It looks like it cannot see to that inner document.

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying this same exact thing but when I reach the document within the object you will get a Security Error if protocol, domain, and port don't match:

> "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:49362" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://*******.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

But if you access within the same domain, protocol and port you will have access to the html document inside the object using the contentDocument:

```
$(function () {
            $('#exweb').html('<object id="webloader" data="http://*****.com"/>');
        });

 <script>
        $(window).load(function () {           
            var html = document.getElementById('webloader').contentDocument           
        });
    </script>
```